# I'm getting Permission Denied when redirecting output from CMD to a text file using the logitech_dfu tool

Tags: command-line-interface, ntfs, windows-command-prompt, redirection, firmware

I've gotten this output using this command you see here from the Logitech instructions, and using the ">" operator before the file names in said command. It errors, and does not place anything in the output and error files. first it lists the devices, like the receiver, my keyboard, and mouse. then it lists the prerequisite firmware files I have in the same place for the program to pull from.

C:\Users\jbadmin\Downloads\Script DFU Tool\Script DFU Tool>Logitech_dfu --output c:\temp\dfu_log.txt --error c:\temp\dfu_err.txt --list --fw_version --available --pre-requisite
Failed to redirect error stream to "c:\temp\dfu_err.txt": Permission denied
Failed to redirect output stream to "c:\temp\dfu_log.txt": Permission denied

1     USB Receiver

1.1   MX Keys

1.2   MX Master 3

1     RQR12.08_B0030

1.1   MPK12.00_B0011

1.2   MPM19.00_B0013

1     RQR12.05_B0028, RQR12.07_B0029, RQR12.08_B0030
1.1

1.2

1

1.1

1.2

C:\Users\jbadmin\Downloads\Script DFU Tool\Script DFU Tool>

This is the tool I'm using from Logitech.
Enterprise customers: You can download a centrally deployable tool for PC here: https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/keyboards/Script%20DFU%20Tool.zip (Mac support will be added shortly)

I'm not sure what to do, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if you can create a file through Windows (File)Explorer in c:\temp without getting a so called UAC prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is a *very* old machine you're running on, the "TEMP" directory *isn't* where you *think* it is; not any more.

Try using the %TEMP% environment variable instead.

```
Logitech_dfu --output "%TEMP%\dfu_log.txt" --error "%TEMP%\dfu_err.txt" ...
```

Alternatively, if you're deliberately created the C:\Temp directory, check the permissions on it, *as seen by* whichever account is running the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Take ownership of `C:\Temp` by `takeown /f C:\Temp` and then grant full access to Users group by `icacls C:\Temp /grant Users:F`.